# Growing an encrypted RAID5 array without causing alignment issues

Tags: linux, software-raid, lvm, mdadm, luks

### Question

Is there anyway to tell mdadm to make sure a certain logical sector on the RAID-device stays aligned to the beginning of a stripe when growing a RAID5 array?

### Problem

My RAID5 is encrypted with LUKS and LVM on top which each have some metadata on the underlaying device which means my actual filesystem starts at sector 6144, which is at the beginning of the third stripe since my chunk size is 512K and I have 4 discs in the array. I assume growing the array with one disc would increase the stripe size and bring that sector to the middle of the second stripe, causing a misalignment and degraded performance.

Is there any way to prevent or mitigate this?

### Desired solution

I think the **best solution** would be to somehow tell mdadm when growing the array to make sure that sector 6144 stays aligned to the beginning of a stripe, but as far as I know this is **not implemented**. It could do this by modify the mapping such that after the growth is complete sector 0 will actually correspond to sector 2048 in the middle of the first stripe, then sector 6144 would correspond to sector 8192 at the beginning of the third stripe.